# Where to get SSL certificate for Android/Air/iOS apps and type

Tags: android, ios, air, ssl-certificate

I'm working on releasing my first app and I have been using a self signed certificate. With a mass release was thinking I should have one from say verisign, etc. I see certificates for websites but im not sure that will work for apps. It would be great to be able to sign my iOS, adobe air and android apps with the same SSL. Or can you only self sign since you need both the public and private keys. I'm pretty much a nub when it comes to SSL certs so flog me if needed.

Comment: For Android, see http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing Android apps requires a certificate that needs to be valid for at least 25 (IIRC) years or more. Practically no CA out there will issue one, because their own validity is typically less than that. So you pretty much need to use a self-signed one for Android. Also make sure that you back up your keystore, because if you lose it, you will need to re-publish your app.

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications are signed using certificates under a totally separate trust chain (run by Apple). While you could perhaps use the same private key as for your web site's SSL key, there is no benefit whatsoever in doing so, and some significant security drawbacks in doing so.

I'm not sure where Air and Android stand, but I suspect that they're generally similar.

Comment: That will be the bigger question then, what trust chain android/google market uses... back to google...